# Prove that number of times $3$ divides $2^n\pm1$ is exactly one more than the number of times $3$ divides $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, p-adic-number-theory, mersenne-numbers

**TL;DR** How to prove the eight congruences at the end of this post?

---

*Remark. My number theory is rusty and I'm trying to prove the following observations.*

*Motivation:* This result easily implies that [$3^n$ does not divide $8^n+1$ for $n\geq 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3626800/318073), for example, as shown in my suggested answer on the linked question.

---

> *Definition.* $\mathbb v_p(a)$ = The $p$-adic order of number $a$ is the number of times $p$ divides $a$.

When I start observing congruence classes, it is easy for me to see the initial observations:

$$\begin{array}{}
\mathbf v_3(2^n-1) =\begin{cases} \mathbf v_3(n) + 1, & n\text{ even}\\0, & n\text{ odd} \end{cases} \\
\mathbf v_3(2^n+1) =\begin{cases}0, & n\text{ even}\\ \mathbf v_3(n) + 1, & n\text{ odd} \end{cases} 
\end{array}$$

In other words, I've actually observed that:

$$\begin{array}{}
\mathbb v_3(2^n-1)=\begin{cases}
0, & n\equiv1\pmod{2}\\
1, & n\equiv2,4\pmod{6}\\
2, & n\equiv6,12\pmod{18}\\
3, & n\equiv18,36\pmod{54}\\
\dots\\
k, & n\equiv2\cdot3^{k-1},4\cdot 3^{k-1}\pmod{2\cdot 3^{k}}\\
\dots
\end{cases}
\\
\mathbb v_3(2^n+1)=\begin{cases}
0, & n\equiv0\pmod{2}\\
1, & n\equiv1,5\pmod{6}\\
2, & n\equiv3,15\pmod{18}\\
3, & n\equiv9,45\pmod{54}\\
\dots\\
k, & n\equiv1\cdot3^{k-1},5\cdot 3^{k-1}\pmod{2\cdot 3^{k}}\\
\dots
\end{cases}
\end{array}$$

Where notice that when we realize $k-1 = \mathbf v_3(n)$, the initial observations follow.

> My question is, how would we formally and rigorously prove these observations?

---

*Below is a possible starting point for the rigorous proof:*

It seems to me like a starting point would be to notice that by definition:

$\space\space\space\space$ 1) $k\le\mathbf v_3(2^n\mp1)$ $\iff$ $2^n \pm1\equiv 0\pmod{3^{k}}$

$\space\space\space\space$ 2) $\mathbf v_3(2^n\mp1)\le k$ $\iff$ ${2^n}\pm1\not\equiv 0\pmod{3^{k+1}}$

Where depending on "$\mp$" we have:

$\space\space\space\space$ a) $ n\equiv2\cdot 3^{k-1}\pmod{2\cdot 3^{k}}$ or $ n\equiv4\cdot3^{k-1}\pmod{2\cdot 3^{k}}$

$\space\space\space\space$ b) $ n\equiv1\cdot 3^{k-1}\pmod{2\cdot 3^{k}}$ or $n\equiv5\cdot3^{k-1}\pmod{2\cdot 3^{k}}$

Now we need to prove that:

- a) implies the RHS of 1) and RHS of 2) for "$-$"
- b) implies the RHS of 1) and RHS of 2) for "$+$"

After proving that, we would have the implications: LHS $\iff$ RHS.

Finally, LHS of 1) combined with LHS of 2) would imply the observations.

To state the implications:

We can use a corollary of [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to obtain the implications:

a) implies the RHS of 1) and RHS of 2) for "$-$":

$$\begin{array}{}
n \equiv 2\cdot3^{k-1} \quad(\bmod 2\cdot3^{k})
&\implies 2^{n} \equiv 2^{2\cdot3^{k-1}} \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\\
n \equiv 4\cdot3^{k-1} \quad(\bmod 2\cdot3^{k})
&\implies 2^{n} \equiv 2^{4\cdot3^{k-1}} \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\end{array}$$

b) implies the RHS of 1) and RHS of 2) for "$+$":

$$\begin{array}{}
n \equiv 1\cdot3^{k-1} \quad(\bmod 2\cdot3^{k})
&\implies 2^{n} \equiv 2^{1\cdot3^{k-1}} \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\\
n \equiv 5\cdot3^{k-1} \quad(\bmod 2\cdot3^{k})
&\implies 2^{n} \equiv 2^{5\cdot3^{k-1}} \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\end{array}$$

To finish the proof, we have to prove:

$$\begin{array}{}
2^{2\cdot3^{k-1}} \not\equiv  +1\quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\\
2^{4\cdot3^{k-1}} \not\equiv  +1 \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{}
2^{1\cdot3^{k-1}} \not\equiv -1 \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\\
2^{5\cdot3^{k-1}} \not\equiv -1 \quad(\bmod 3^{k+1})
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{}
2^{2\cdot3^{k-1}} \equiv  +1\quad(\bmod 3^{k})
\\
2^{4\cdot3^{k-1}} \equiv  +1 \quad(\bmod 3^{k})
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{}
2^{1\cdot3^{k-1}} \equiv -1 \quad(\bmod 3^{k})
\\
2^{5\cdot3^{k-1}} \equiv -1 \quad(\bmod 3^{k})
\end{array}$$

But I'm not sure how to prove these eight congruences.

Comment: I think all this this follows quickly  from the properties of the $p$-adic logarithm (for $p=3$) $log: (1+p\mathbb Z_p, \cdot) \simeq (\mathbb Z_p,+)$ and just observing in which filtration step of the $3$-adic unit group small powers of $2$ lie, but maybe you don't want to use such a big hammer?

Comment: Actually, one does not need the logarithm, just "well-known" results about how the $p$-power map operates on the higher principal unit groups.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'm actually not familiar with p-adic number theory, but I did once read something little about it somewhere and remembered that my observation on these congruences actually represents the p-adic order. If you have any suggestions on reading material that would be cool. If not, still thank you for your comment for giving me some more context.

Comment: Naturally, books on p-adic numbers  contain discussions of this. Good short treatments might be in sources on local class field theory (where it's a preliminary; the goal is then to relate the filtration of the unit group to filtrations of Galois extensions), I remember a succinct one in Neukirch's "Class Field Theory". A decent free online source is https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmzibf/book/vol.pdf, chapter I sec. 5 and 6. Raising to the $p$-th power is discussed in 5.6 et seq., all far more general and hence a little abstract compared to what we need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Equivalences for Induction**

Since $2^6\equiv1\pmod9$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
2^{6m+1}+1&\equiv3\pmod9\tag1\\
2^{6m+2}-1&\equiv3\pmod9\tag2\\
2^{6m+4}-1&\equiv6\pmod9\tag3\\
2^{6m+5}+1&\equiv6\pmod9\tag4\\
\end{align}
$$

If $n$ is even, $n\in\{0,2,4\}\pmod6$, $2^{2n}+2^n+1\equiv3\pmod9$ and
$$
\left(2^{2n}+2^n+1\right)\left(2^n-1\right)=\left(2^{3n}-1\right)\tag5
$$
If $n$ is odd, $n\in\{1,3,5\}\pmod6$, $2^{2n}-2^n+1\equiv3\pmod9$ and
$$
\left(2^{2n}-2^n+1\right)\left(2^n+1\right)=\left(2^{3n}+1\right)\tag6
$$

---

**Applying the Equivalences**

Let $P(k)$ be the statement that $v_3(n)=k\implies v_3\!\left(2^n-(-1)^n\right)=k+1$.

$P(0)$ is verified by $(1)-(4)$.

$P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ is verified by $(5)-(6)$.

Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{v_3\!\left(2^n-(-1)^n\right)=v_3(n)+1}\tag7
$$

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But, I'm trying to directly prove $2^n\pm1$ is divisible by $3^k$ and is not divisible by $3^{k+1}$, which would directly imply $\mathbf v_3(2^n\pm1)=k=\mathbf v_3(n)+1$ for corresponding parity of $n$. That is, I've edited the post to hopefully make it clear that I want to know how to prove the eight congruences at the end of my post, if possible.

Comment: I have added more of the induction.

Comment: Ah I see it the induction is indeed a simpler and nicer proof than what I tried. I was hoping to learn how would one directly evaluate the eight congruences that appear in my brute force proof, but if that isn't given, I'll eventually accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

More generally,

$$ (p+(-1))^n-(-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k p^{n-k} $$

and now note that the term for $k=n-1$ on the RHS has $p$-adic valuation $v_p(n\cdot p) = v_p(n)+1$, whereas for odd (!) primes $p$, all terms with $k \le n-2$ have strictly higher valuation. Consequently,

$$v_p \left[(p-1)^n - (-1)^n\right]=v_p(n)+1$$
for all odd primes $p$ and $n \ge 1$. Yours is the case $p=3$.

Comment: This does now remind me of LTE lemma that I've just now found out about. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: (+1) The Lemma from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426929) shows that for any prime $p\gt2$ and for $j\ge2$, $p^k\,|\,n\implies\left.p^{k-j+2}\,\middle|\,\binom{n}{j}\right.$, which means that $\left.p^{k+2}\,\middle|\,\binom{n}{j}p^j\right.$. This validates your claim regarding the valuation of the extra terms.

Comment: Vepir, yes, this is a special case of the LTE lemma. @robjohn: Thanks for amending a validation for that. I got the idea for this answer from the final rephrasing of the statement in your answer, which I also upvoted.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: yes, writing it that way, I was thinking of adding an answer using the Binomial Theorem, but you wrote yours first. This is nice in its generality.